# Socket.io 404 Error - Client not connecting

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

When deploying a twitter streaming app which is working well on my local environment, to a live webserver, I'm getting a 404 error related to socket.io. I saw that there a numerous similar questions here already but did not find an answer solving the problem I'm facing.

Problem description:

1. Once I start server.js, it correctly logs 'Listening on Port 3000' to the console (terminal)
2. However, the message "Client connected..." is not triggered
3. In the browser console, I'm seeing the error message "GET https://exampledomain.com/socket.io/?EIO................(etc) - 404 - XHR failed loading"

I have already tried the following changes without success, amongst other things:

1. Changed the server.js code from `const http = require('http')` to `const https = require('https')`
2. Changed the port from 3000 to others to rule out a certain port # is already in use elsewhere, e.g. 8001 or 3333

The full server code (in public_html/server/**server.js**):

```
const http = require('http')
const path = require('path')
const express = require('express')
const socketIo = require('socket.io')
const needle = require('needle')
const config = require('dotenv').config()
const TWITTER_BEARER_TOKEN = 'xxxxxx'

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000

const app = express()

const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = socketIo(server)

console.log(path.resolve(__dirname, '../', 'public_html/client', 'index.html'))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../', 'public_html/client', 'index.html'))
  // /usr/www/users/antick/public_html/client/index.html
})


const rulesURL = 'https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/stream/rules'
const streamURL = 'https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/stream?tweet.fields=public_metrics&expansions=author_id,attachments.media_keys&media.fields=duration_ms,height,media_key,preview_image_url,public_metrics,type,url,width&user.fields=profile_image_url'

const rules = [{ value: 'corruption' }]

// Get stream rules
async function getRules() {
  const response = await needle('get', rulesURL, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${TWITTER_BEARER_TOKEN}`
    }
  })
  return response.body
}

// Set stream rules
async function setRules() {
  const data = {
    add: rules
  }

  const response = await needle('post', rulesURL, data, {
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${TWITTER_BEARER_TOKEN}`
    }
  })

  return response.body
}

// Delete stream rules
async function deleteRules(rules) {

  if (!Array.isArray(rules.data)) {
    return null
  }

  const ids = rules.data.map((rule) => rule.id)

  const data = {
    delete: {
      ids: ids
    }
  }

  const response = await needle('post', rulesURL, data, {
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${TWITTER_BEARER_TOKEN}`
    }
  })

  return response.body
}

function streamTweets(socket) {
  const stream = needle.get(streamURL, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${TWITTER_BEARER_TOKEN}`
    }
  })

  stream.on('data', (data) => {
    try {
      const json = JSON.parse(data)
      console.log(json)

      socket.emit('tweet', json)
    } catch (error) {}
  })
}

io.on('connection', async () => {
  console.log('Client connected...')

  let currentRules

  try {
    // Get all stream rules
    currentRules = await getRules()

    // Delete all stream rules
    await deleteRules(currentRules)

    // Set rules based on array above (Rules)
    await setRules()
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    process.exit(1)
  }

  streamTweets(io)
})

server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on Port ${PORT}`))
```

My client code - excerpt only (in public_html/client/**index.html**):

```
<div class="container">
     <div id="tweetStream"></div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.1.2/socket.io.js" integrity="sha512-iZIBSs+gDyTH0ZhUem9eQ1t4DcEn2B9lHxfRMeGQhyNdSUz+rb+5A3ummX6DQTOIs1XK0gOteOg/LPtSo9VJ+w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer">
</script>

<script>
        const tweetStream = document.getElementById('tweetStream')
        const socket = io()
        //const socket = io.connect('https://www.exampledomain.com:3000/');
        const tweets = []

        socket.on('connect', () => {
            console.log('Connected to server...')
        })

        socket.on('tweet', (tweet) => {

// (code continues here)
```

My suspicion is that is has to do something with the paths used in these two locations:

1. in server/server.js:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../', 'public_html/client', 'index.html'))
  // resolves to:   /usr/www/users/antick/public_html/client/index.html
})
```

2. in client/index.html: `const socket = io()` //

What else could possibly cause the error described above? I am grateful for any help. Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `https://exampledomain.com:3000/socket.io/` ?

Comment: Double check your cloudflare (if you're using it) settings to allow websocket connections. Also open up the socket.io url in the browser, `https://www.anticorruptionwatch.com:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js` i think, your server should generate one

Comment: @BrahmaDev that's a very good point. Where in the code shown can I add that folder?

Comment: @Pogrindis the link does not seem to work, do you have any suggestion what I'm missing? I am not using CloudFlare.

Comment: On your socket.io connection use another port appart from the tcp port. so something like : `require('socket.io')(3001)`

Then in your client use that port instead when connecting. `io.connect('http://www.exampledomain.com:3001/');`

Comment: @Pogrindis if I add `const socketIo = require('socket.io')(3001)` then I get an error message ("socketIo is not a function) at the following line: `const io = socketIo(server)`

Comment: Right, you dont need to define io because you've already instanciated the server on 3001.  you can just use `const io = require('socket.io')(3001)` if you like

Comment: @Pogrindis thank you, I commented out `//const socketIo = require('socket.io')`and added `const io = require('socket.io')(3002)` plus on the client side `const socket = io.connect('http://www.example.com:3002/')` now. The 404 error in the browser is gone and I'm seeing a "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT" instead for each GET request. The terminal says "listening on Port 3000" (I did not change the `const port = 3000` line). Still, the connection to the client seemingly isn't established and tweets aren't loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from a pro developer I was finally able to fix the problem so I would like to post the solution.

The two main points were:

1. Open Port # 3000 to any IPs (as it is unknown from which IP address a client would access the site)
2. Install pm2 in addition to node in order to constantly stream the tweets

The full resulting code looks as follows:

A) Server (index.js):

```
const http = require('http')
const path = require('path')
const express = require('express')
const socketIo = require('socket.io')
const needle = require('needle')
const config = require('dotenv').config()
const TOKEN = process.env.TWITTER_BEARER_TOKEN
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000

const app = express()

const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = socketIo(server)

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../', 'client', 'index.html'))
})


const rulesURL = 'https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/stream/rules'

const streamURL = 'https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/stream?tweet.fields=public_metrics&expansions=author_id,attachments.media_keys&media.fields=duration_ms,height,media_key,preview_image_url,public_metrics,type,url,width&user.fields=profile_image_url'

const rules = [{ value: 'searchterm' }]

// Get stream rules
async function getRules() {
    const response = await needle('get', rulesURL, {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${TOKEN}`
        }
    })
    return response.body
}

// Set stream rules
async function setRules() {
    const data = {
        add: rules 
    }

    const response = await needle('post', rulesURL, data, {
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${TOKEN}`
        }
    })

    return response.body
}

// Delete stream rules
async function deleteRules(rules) {

    if(!Array.isArray(rules.data)) {
        return null 
    }

    const ids = rules.data.map((rule) => rule.id)

    const data = {
        delete: {
            ids: ids 
        } 
    }

    const response = await needle('post', rulesURL, data, {
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${TOKEN}`
        }
    })

    return response.body
}

function streamTweets (socket) {
    const stream = needle.get(streamURL, {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${TOKEN}`
        }
    })

    stream.on('data', (data) => {
        try {
            const json = JSON.parse(data)
            console.log(json)
            console.log(json.includes.media[0])

            socket.emit('tweet', json)
        } catch (error) {}
    })
}

io.on('connection', async () => {
    console.log('Client connected...')

    let currentRules

    try {
        // Get all stream rules
        currentRules = await getRules()

        // Delete all stream rules
        await deleteRules(currentRules)

        // Set rules based on array above (Rules)
        await setRules()
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
        process.exit(1)
    }

    streamTweets(io)
})

server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on Port ${PORT}`))
```

B) Client (index.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css"
      integrity="sha512-+4zCK9k+qNFUR5X+cKL9EIR+ZOhtIloNl9GIKS57V1MyNsYpYcUrUeQc9vNfzsWfV28IaLL3i96P9sdNyeRssA=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <title>Real-Time Tweet Stream</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Real-Time Tweet Stream</a>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
      <div id="tweetStream"></div>
    </div>

    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/3.0.4/socket.io.js"
      integrity="sha512-aMGMvNYu8Ue4G+fHa359jcPb1u+ytAF+P2SCb+PxrjCdO3n3ZTxJ30zuH39rimUggmTwmh2u7wvQsDTHESnmfQ=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <script>
      const tweetStream = document.getElementById('tweetStream')
      const socket = io('IP.IP.IP.IP:3000'  , { transports : ['websocket'] } ) // webserver IP address

      const tweets = []

      socket.on('connect', () => {
        console.log('Connected to server...')
      })

      socket.on('tweet', (tweet) => {
        // console.log(tweet)
        const tweetData = {
          id: tweet.data.id,
          text: tweet.data.text,
          username: `@${tweet.includes.users[0].username}`,
        }

        const tweetEl = document.createElement('div')
        tweetEl.className = 'card my-4'
        tweetEl.innerHTML = `
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">${tweetData.text}</h5>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">${tweetData.username}</h6>
                
                <a class="btn btn-primary mt-3" href="https://twitter.com/${tweetData.username}/status/${tweetData.id}">
                    <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i> Go To Tweet    
                </a>
            </div>
        `

        tweetStream.appendChild(tweetEl)

      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```